# Measure real size of irregular shapes in picture

Tags: opencv, math, shapes, emgucv, measurement

I have two "contours" shapes in a array, one contourn is the square that i know his real size, and the other is the mole that i need to make the proportional measurement.
Here is the image example:

[image]

The square has 10x10mm, how can i know the size of the other shape based on the square?

What i tried so far is this:

```
var molePerimeter = CvInvoke.ArcLength(contours[0], false);
double moleArea = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[0], false);
var squarePerimeter = CvInvoke.ArcLength(squares[0], true);
double squareArea = CvInvoke.ContourArea(squares[0], false);
textBox2.AppendText("Area: " + squareArea / moleArea);
textBox2.AppendText("perimeter: " + squarePerimeter / molePerimeter);
```

But i dont thinks that is corret.

Comment: 1) You need to ensure/assume that the camera axis is perpendicular to the white square else you will introduce distortions, i.e. that the mole is the same distance from the camera as the white square. 2) Do you want to know the area, the perimeter or the major/minor axes of the mole?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I will get the perimeter, area and the length of mole. Knowing that the square is 1x1cm i will try to get the real size. But how i calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the mole is probably in a circular shape, You may use [`cv::boundingRect()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366), it would return you a `cv::Rect()`, which you may use to get the rectangular dimensions of the mole.

similarly you have the rectangular dimensions of the white patch. Say the dimensions of mole are (w1 x h1) and that of white patch are (w2 x h2).

Now to calculate the dimension of mole w.r.t real world dimensions:

```
real_w_patch, real_h_patch = 10, 10

real_w_mole = w1/w2 * real_w_patch
real_h_mole = h1/h2 * real_h_patch
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that all the variables are either in float or double to make precise calculations.

Comment: The result will be in "pixels"?

Comment: No the result would in the same dimensions as of the white patch `mm` in this case.